# How to get the list of files in a directory and display them in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Actually I'll get the directory name dynamically from one url.I want to display the list of files in a directory in the html table.How can I do this ?

Comment: Come to SO with a specific question about code that is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you maybe get directory name - ask server. It must have available functionality to scan directory, or get name. And expose it via REST, (while ajax)
And from browser, request this endpoint

Comment: can u please edit the code here